# How to assign value of generic conditional infer type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics

I try to make these conditional infer types works:

```
type A<T> = T extends { a: infer U } ? U : never
type B<T> = T extends { a: infer U } ? U : never

class Test<K extends { a: string }> {
  constructor(props: string) {
    // Error: string is not assignable to A<K>
    let a: A<K> = props
    // Error
    let b: B<K> = props
    // Error: B<K> is not assignable to A<K>
    a = b
  }
}
```

It's wired that both `A<K>` and `B<K>` have the same definition but cannot assign to each other.
I cannot understand both `A<K>` and `B<K>` should be string type at compile time but cannot accept `string` value.
Any way to make it work?

Comment: The `a = b` line [does not error in TS3.7](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggPAFQHxQLxQVCAPYEB2AJgM5QDeUAhgFxQCW+AZhAE5QCqUAvlAPwdRa+CADdWAKFCQoAIUQp0mHHiKkKNek1YCe-TkNETxjAK74AxsDoB7fFEaIsuAiXJVaxYCwYBzbkgAKDXhkABooACNaOWQASnJxKEi0KgBucS5xIA).  Not sure which PR fixed that.

Comment: For the rest of it: TypeScript can't reason well about conditional types that depend on an unresolved generic type parameter. You'll have better luck with `K["a"]` instead of `A<K>`, since you're just [looking up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) a property type.  Be warned that it's still not fully safe, if `K` has a [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) type for `a` like `new Test<{a: "z"}>("oops");`.. which assigns `"oops"` to a value of type `"z"`.

Comment: @jcalz I am using 3.6.4. The error exists.

Comment: @jcalz Anyway, my use case is using a pattern match like `type Listener<T> = (...args: ListenerArgsType<T>) => void` which is used as `Listener<TypedEventMap[E]>` to convert a event map type to a regular listener function type. String is one of the type of event map value to infer.

Answer (score 0):

As @jcalz said, TS3.7 fixed it.